# Razor-Page: render a complete page (chstml+chstml.cs)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0, razor-pages

As far as I understand the Partial pages have only the cshtml code, while the ViewComponent have only the cs code.
Perhaps my approach is wrong, but I'm trying to render a complete page (cshtml + cshtml.cs) in another.

Real example. 
Visual Studio 2017, ASP.NET Core 2.

NavBar.cshtml:

```
@page
@model MyProject.NavBarModel

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" asp-page="/Machines">@Resources.Machines</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">@Resources.Orders</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" asp-page="/RunningOrders">@Resources.Running <span class="badge badge-primary">@ViewData["running"]</span></a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" asp-page="/OpenOrders">@Resources.Opened <span class="badge badge-primary">@ViewData["running"]</span></a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" asp-page="/SuspendedOrders">@Resources.Suspended <span class="badge badge-danger">@ViewData["running"]</span></a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" asp-page="/Tables">@Resources.Lists</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" asp-page="/About">@Resources.About</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

NavBar.cshtml.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MyProject.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class NavBarModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly MyContext _context;

        public NavBarModel(MyContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            Orders = await _context.Orders.ToListAsync();

            ViewData["open"] = _context.Orders.Where(x => x.State == OrderStates.Open).Count();
            ViewData["running"] = _context.Orders.Where(x => x.State == OrderStates.Running).Count();
            ViewData["suspened"] = _context.Orders.Where(x => x.State == OrderStates.Suspended).Count();
        }
    }
}
```

_Layout.cshtml:

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top mb-2">
        <a asp-page="/Index" class="navbar-brand">Production Assistant</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        @Html.Partial("NavBar", new NavBarModel())

    </nav>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
```

In this example I'm trying to add a Badge in the Navbar. Because the _Layout file has no code behind I had to put that in a separate Page (NavBar).

The problem is that when I try to render the page it asks for the constructor parameters. I'm afraid I've broken the dependency injection in this way.

Comment: NavBarModel has only one constructor, that needs the MyContext as parameter, thats why.

Comment: Yes, it is what I meant with "I've broken the dependency injection". I cannot provide the Context directly, it's passed by the d.i.

Comment: also, it's a bad pratice coupling the data provider to your model. You should use repository pattern + dto instead injecting the context on your model.

Comment: Well, it's suggested in the official documentation, i.e.: https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/data/ef-rp/intro/samples/cu/Pages/Students/Details.cshtml.cs

Comment: @Mark I personally have found that many Microsoft examples show anti-patterns.  In this example, the model should not know about how it's populated, that is not a ViewModels [responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).  The reason is that once the model makes it to the page, depending on how the data access is configured, it would be easy to throw an exception in a view while access model data, that's a huge no no.

Comment: @ErikPhilips got it, but I'm learning reading the official documentation... in the next project I will try to find another source to learn

Comment: @Mark no problem, but just understand that the official documentation gives examples on how to use `/`(division operator) and may even show an example dividing by zero, but advanced programmers know that catching an `DivideByZeroException` means there is code that is wrong because it [should never be thrown](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/) to begin with.